# Implementing caching with Redis

Tags: sqlite, caching, redis

I have a dotnet web api, with react app, and SQLite database, I want to implement caching with Redis, How in details?
I'm using vscode.

I'm new for using Redis, I followed many videos but getting errors and start over many times.